# Best way to handle large number of items in a listview?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am making an application in vb.net that involves listing a large number of files in a listview. However, after 30-40 000 items this gets rather slow and resource demanding. I need a better way to present a large number of items to users. I have though of using pages much like google search results showing 1000 items per page... I have also though of switching between sets of items every time the user hits min and max scrolling position.

What would be the best slution to handeling and presenting large numbers of items in listview? thanks.

Comment: Consider using a lazy load technique, per this thread:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: If you're listing files, have you considered using a treeview instead? I might make the UI a little neater and you then only need populate nodes as they are expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing large amount of items in a listview is always not a good solution as it cause performance and memory issues. Also the user could not see all the items in a single scroll. So always choose to show items with less amount of data. But some requirements may force to show large number of items. **VirtualizationPanel** and **VirtualizationStackPanel** is a solution to improve the UI responsiveness and performance by recycling and loading items based on the scrolling like Windows Explorer.

Please see the below links will helps you to solve your problems

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel(v=vs.90).aspx